# How can I add a column to a dataframe with a value conditional on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with two dataframes:

Dataframe1 looks like:

| user (index) | apples | bananas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | 4 | 2 |
| Sara | 5 | 10 |
| Kara | 4 | 2 |
| Tom | 3 | 3 |

Dataframe2 looks like:

| index | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pete |
| 2 | Sara |

I want to create a new boolean column in dataframe1 that is true if the user is in dataframe 2. So output looks like:

| user | apples | bananas | new column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | 4 | 2 | True |
| Sara | 5 | 10 | True |
| Kara | 4 | 2 | False |
| Tom | 3 | 3 | False |

I tried using lambda function but didn't get very far.

Comment: Why not use `df1['new column'] = df1['user (index)'].isin(df2['user'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way of doing that.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df2['new_column']=True

df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='user', right_on='user', how = 'left')
df.new_column.fillna(False, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `indicator` param of [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Then use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
In [598]: x = df1.merge(df2['user'], left_on='user (index)', right_on='user', how='left', indicator='new column').replace({'both': True, 'left_only':False}).drop('user', 1)

In [599]: x
Out[599]: 
  user (index)  apples  bananas  new column
0         Pete       4        2        True
1         Sara       5       10        True
2         Kara       4        2       False
3          Tom       3        3       False
```

**OR:**

For some better performance, use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) instead of `df.replace`:

```
In [609]: y = df1.merge(df2['user'], left_on='user (index)', right_on='user', how='left', indicator='new column').drop('user', 1)

In [611]: y['new column'] = y['new column'].map({'both': True, 'left_only':False})

In [612]: y
Out[612]: 
  user (index)  apples  bananas new column
0         Pete       4        2       True
1         Sara       5       10       True
2         Kara       4        2      False
3          Tom       3        3      False
```